# Handling extremely large Numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pickle, large-data, dump

I want to create a Numpy kernel matrix of dimensions 25000*25000. I want to know what is the most efficient way to handle such large matrix in terms of saving it on disk and loading it. I tried dumping it with Pickle, but it threw an error saying it cannot serialize objects of size greater than 4 Gib.

Comment: try np.save or np.savez

Comment: Not from a lot of experience, but you might want to look at [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/numpy.html) and also at [parquet](http://parquet.apache.org/). `pyarrow` is supposed to already contains parquet.

Answer (score 1):

u could try to save it in h5 file by pandas.HDFStore()

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(25000,25000).astype('float16'))
memory_use = round(df.memory_usage(deep=True).sum()/1024*3,2)
print('use{}G'.format(memory_use))
store = pd.HDFStore('test.h5', 'w)
store['data'] = df
store.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try to save the array as a file instead of using pickle

```
np.savetxt("filename",array)
```

It then can be read by

np.genfromtxt("filename")

Comment: Both the save and load will be very slow with this large of an array.